# Accessing a rails test server remotely

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Maybe I'm missing something simple here, but when I run "ruby script/server", I can access it through localhost, but not remotely. Is there something simple I can do to access it remotely without doing some fancy deployment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass -b option which can bind to an IP address. Suppose your test server IP address is `192.168.1.10`

```
script/server -b 192.168.1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
bin/rails s -b <YOUR_IP>
```